# Cypress how to stop route or only route a url request one time

Tags: cypress

I use cy.route to stab a specific URL request. But the URL request will be sent many times.
I just want to stab the first time. How to do that.

Comment: Would you share some code of your tests and the app you're trying to access?

Comment: what about spliting them into different test cases? The stub should only work in one single test case unless you specify it.